# Hanoi Tower Problem using stacks - It is not solving the hanoi problem but moving the disks

Tags: c, stack, towers-of-hanoi

```
    //Stack Study by yoonseul at 210719

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define SIZE 9
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

typedef struct {
    int item[SIZE];
    int top;
} Stack;

void InitStack(Stack* pstack)
{
    pstack->top = -1;
}

bool IsFull(Stack* pstack)
{
    return pstack->top == SIZE - 1;
}

bool IsEmpty(Stack* pstack)
{
        return pstack->top == -1
}

int Peek(Stack* pstack)
{
    if (IsEmpty(pstack)) {
        return -1;
    }
    return pstack->item[pstack->top];
}

void Push(Stack* pstack, int disk)
{
    if (IsFull(pstack)) {
        exit(1);
    }
    pstack->item[++(pstack->top)] = disk;
}

void Pop(Stack* pstack) {
    if (IsEmpty(pstack)) {
        exit(1);
    }
    --(pstack->top);
}

int exchange(int x);

int main()
{
    int num;
    int rod[3][SIZE];
    char from='0', to;
    int move;

    scanf("%d", &num);

    InitStack(&rod[0]);
    InitStack(&rod[1]);
    InitStack(&rod[2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < num+1; i++) {
        Push(&rod[0], i+1);
        Push(&rod[1], 0);
        Push(&rod[2], 0);
    }

    while (from != 'q') {
        printf("%3c %3c %3c\n", 'A', 'B', 'C');
        for (int i = 0;i<num; i++) {
            printf("%3d %3d %3d\n", rod[0][i], rod[1][i], rod[2][i]);
        }


        scanf("%c %c", &from, &to);

        if (from == 'q')
            return 0;
        
        int peekF, peekT;
        int numF = exchange(from);
        int numT = exchange(to);
        
        peekF = Peek(&rod[numF]);
        peekT = Peek(&rod[numT]);

        if (peekF > peekT && peekT != -1) {
            printf("Invalid Move");
        }

        else {
            Pop(&rod[numF]);
            Push(&rod[numT],peekF);
        }

        
    }
}

int exchange(int x)
{
    switch (x) {
        case 'A':
            return 0;
        case 'B':
            return 1;
        case 'C':
            return 2;
    }
}
```

Here is my full code for Hanoi Problem.
The objective is to make a problem that can move this between the rod, and print 'invalid move' if the move is invalid. Also, user can input the number of the disks.
When I debug, there are two errors occur.
One is beneath '   A    B   C' the last number disk is printed three times. My objective is to print '   1   0   0'
(ex. if maximum disk is 3,'   3    3    3' is printed.)
**edited** I solved the first one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < num + 1; i++) {
        Push(&rod[0], i+1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num + 1; i++) {
        Push(&rod[1], 0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num + 1; i++) {
        Push(&rod[2], 0);
    }
```

I changed disk putting part like like using *for* statement three times. but I don't know the reason why this happens.
**Edited**
The hanoi Tower is printed twice, after 2nd scan. I want to know the reason why this happens. It seems like memory problem. I want to know why. I'm new to coding.
PLZ help me. I'm crying.

Comment: Save time, enable all warnings and review return of `bool IsEmpty(Stack* pstack) { if (pstack->top == -1) return true; }` and types passed to `IinitStack(), Peek()`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll change that part.